# Scroll whole height of a div (banner)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a landing page, where will be a banner (`height: 100% - 200px`). And I want, that first scroll down (via mouse wheel / arrow etc.) will scroll down for whole height of banner (`100% of page - 200px`) and then scroll normally rest of a page.

But when you will scroll back there and you will "step" (top of window will be on the bottom of an element) on banner, it will scroll whole height of banner back to top.

I've tried a plugin fullPage.js, but I can't use it, cause it fights with other plugin that I'm using.

Here is a **jsfiddle** with a basic simulation of my page: https://jsfiddle.net/Lua4v1p9/2/
basically, an element ".bann" has to be scrollable on one mouse wheel turn, if I'm describing it well enough.

Here is work version of my page online: http://suju.honzisdesign.cz

I hope, that I described my problem good enough, thanks for any response!

Comment: It seems unclear what you are trying to achieve. Do you have some code to show ?

Comment: You should have a look at that question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling#answer-488073 Then, you could achieve something like "The banner is in view, scroll to top or scroll to bootom of the banner. The banner is not in view, do as usual"

Comment: @SébastienGicquel Yes, I've created a jsfiddle and gave the link for my website. Overall I'm trying to achieve this: https://codepen.io/Javarome/post/full-page-sliding but NOT on a full page sections (fullpage.js does the same), only for height of ".bann", then normal scrolling on the rest of a page.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel basically, an element ".bann" (https://jsfiddle.net/Lua4v1p9/2/) has to be scrollable on one mouse wheel turn, if I'm describing it well enough.